# Import CSV file to MySQL by chunks

Tags: mysql, c, csv, chunks

I have an app that receives a CSV formatted data by 256 bytes chunks.
My goal is to have the file imported to MySQL. As for now, I am saving the entire CSV to a temp file and then import it to MySQL using `IMPORT DATA INFILE ...`.

It works as expected my only doubt is that maybe there is a better solution to import the data in a more efficient way.

Comment: `Import data infile` is actually a really fast way to import data (if there are not only 1 or 2 rows in the file). I would stick with it if it works in your setup (it needs the file to be stored in a place it can access, so it cannot be used in all cases).

Comment: Thanks! And what if the file actually contains only 2 lines of data? :)

Comment: Then read your data, translate it to a proper `insert` statement and send it to the server through a connection. But it's not really only about efficiency then, it's just the cleaner and more portable solution (you don't need the file transfer, you get proper errors, you can use it for data not in a csv, ...). `Load data infile` will get very efficient (10, 20 times faster than `insert`) when you have like 500+ rows, below this the factor will get smaller, and at some rowcount you have to test for yourself it will get equal or even slower because of the overhead.